# How to know the name of all the sub-folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, subdirectory

I have an absolute path of a Folder.Is there any way to know the number of sub-folders it contains and to get the names of all of its sub-folders using JavaScript(nodejs) .
I googled it but could not find any solution.

Comment: You would need a server side language to do this, such as php. but you could use ajax to call a php script that returns the list and then deal with it with JavaScript

Comment: I am trying with Nodejs. Is it possible to do using Nodejs

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure, in future please mention the technologies you are using.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback

Answer (score 1):

You want [the fs module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = '/Users/quentin';
var filenames = fs.readdirSync(path);
var count = 0;
filenames.forEach(function (name) {
    if (name === "." || name === "..") {
        return;
    }
    if (fs.lstatSync(path + "/" + name).isDirectory()) {
        count++;
    }

});
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var uid = process.getuid();
var gid = process.getgid();

function countDirs(dir, depth) {
    if (! depth) return 0;
    depth--;

    var dirs   = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    var result = 0;
    var item, stat;
    while(dirs.length) {
        item = path.join(dir, dirs.shift());
        stat = fs.lstatSync(item);

        if ( ! stat.isDirectory()) continue;
        var mode = stat.mode.toString(8).split();
        result++;
        // If process allowed to read dir
        if (stat.uid === uid || stat.guid === gid && mode[3] > 3 || mode[4] > 3) {
            result += countDirs(item, depth);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
// Example usage
var count = countDirs(process.cwd(), 1);
console.log('Total dirs count:', count);
```

**Note**! Don't forget about permissions!